# Does authlib support refresh my access token when using client credentials?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, authlib

I'm new to authlib, and while checking on the documentation it mentions that it supports "auto-refresh" for `password` grant_type.

I was wondering if the library is able to detect when the currently associated token expired, while using `client_credentials`, and then request a new access token for me. (doing the whole OAuth dance for me)

It seems ugly to check for every call that I need to do, whether I got a 401 and then trigger the action of getting a new token.

Is there a best practice to follow here? can this be added as a decorator somehow?

Answer (score 2):

To add some flavour to the previous answer, I was able to get the refresh_token function to work for a recent API integration.

This had some peculiarities in that I had to pass the client_id and client_secret in the refresh_token call. I also had to set the grant_type. These may not be applicable to the API you're trying to use.

```
from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session

my_token = {'refresh_token':current_refresh_token,
            'access_token': current_access_token,
            'expires_at': current_access_token_expires_at,
            'expires_in': current_access_token_expires_in}

oauth_session = OAuth2Session(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,
                              authorization_endpoint=AUTH_ENDPOINT,
                              token_endpoint=TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
                              token=my_token,
                              grant_type='refresh_token')

    new_token = oauth_session.refresh_token(
                    url=REFRESH_TOKEN_URL,
                    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
                    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will refresh your token automatically, here is the code for that:

https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/master/authlib/integrations/requests_client/oauth2_session.py#L25-L30